# Leaflet - Zoom map to fit several circles leaves big gap on sides

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

On Leaflet, I have several circles in a map that I generate like this:

```
    let allData = [
        ['Berlin', 52.5243700, 13.4105300, 'Germany'], 
        ['Hamburg', 53.551086, 9.993682, 'Germany'], 
        ['Leipzig', 51.33962, 12.37129, 'Germany']
    ]

    let map = L.map('map');

    let circlesArray = []

    for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {

      let latitude = allData[i][1]
      let longitude = allData[i][2]

      circle = L.circle([latitude, longitude], {
            color: 'rgb(112,0,243)',
            fillColor: 'rgba(112, 0, 243, 0.1)',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            radius: 100000
          }).addTo(map);

      circlesArray.push(circle)
    }
    
    let group = new L.featureGroup(circlesArray);
    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Edit: now it works without any warning, but the zoom doesn't totally fit the circles, but leaves a big gap.

[See Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/C93cGQ7FeS0R86Z1)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/qqXhEz9SG6qqOmdh). Beware the lowercase `f` in `new L.featureGroup`.

Comment: Got it working in this plunkr with my code, but it doesn't totally fit the map to the circles (neither in your map, at least with FF) https://plnkr.co/edit/C93cGQ7FeS0R86Z1

Comment: Has to do with plnkr resizing the iframe, and Leaflet not doing a `invalidateSize`. Still, there's no visible error - this means that if the problem in your question is not reproducible, which means your question is kinda invalid.

Comment: Edited to reflect that there is now no console errors/warnings, but zoom is not totally fitting the circles but leaving a big gap (it also happens in my local, not just in Plunkr).

Comment: Perfect, feel free to post the answer and I'll mark it as valid (as the question is slightly different imo) Cheers!